# Text reading with Tesseract in a noisy image

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract

I have these two images:

[image]

[image]

the first one has clearly an higher quality then the second one (even if it hasn't such a bad quality). I process the two images with OpenCV in order to read the text with Tesseract like that:

```
import tesseract
import cv2

img = cv2.cvtColor(scr_crop, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 220, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# Create custom kernel
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))
# Perform closing (dilation followed by erosion)
close = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# Invert image to use for Tesseract
result = 255 - close

# result = cv2.resize(result, (0, 0), fx=2, fy=2)

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(result, lang="ita")
```

So I perform first a dilation and then an erosion for the gray-scaled versions of the two images obtaining these two results for the two images

[image]

[image]

So, as you can see, for the first image I obtain a great result and tessaract is able to read the text while I obtain a bad result for the second image and tesseract is not able to read the text. How can I improve the quality of the second image in order to obtain a better result for tesseract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second image, just apply `only thresholding` with different threshold types.

Instead of `cv2.THRESH_BINARY`, use `cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU`

Image will become:

[image]

and if you read:

```py
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(threshold)
print(txt)
```

Result will be:

```py
Esiti Positivi: 57

Esiti Negativi: 1512
Numerosita: 1569

Tasso di Conversione: 3.63%
```

Now what does `cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV` and `cv2.THRESH_OTSU` means?

`cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV` is the opposite operation of the `cv2.THRESH_BINARY` if the current pixel value is greater than the threshold set to the 0. `maxval` ((255 in our case), otherwise.

[image]

[source](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ggaa9e58d2860d4afa658ef70a9b1115576a19120b1a11d8067576cc24f4d2f03754)

`cv2.THRESH_OTSU` finds the optimal threshold value using the [OTSU's](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/MORSE/threshold.pdf) algorithm. [page 3]

Code:

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread("c7xq9.png")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thr = cv2.threshold(gry, 220, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr)
print(txt)
cv2.imshow("thr", thr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```